# Is the direction of current wrong in this circuit? Why?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, conventions

I know how to measure the equivalent resistance of this circuit, we say R2, R3 and R4 are in parallel combination and I know the reason of this too. But if we consider the direction of electricity of the circuit like this figure, so that no electricity is going through resistance-2 (R2). In that case R3 and R4 are in parallel combination which is connected with R1 in series. This time the equivalent resistance is not the same as first time. Is the direction of the current wrong? Why? What is my mistake? [image: Figure 1]

Edit:
-I don't want to simplify the circuit. I just want to see the current flow in present figure.

- The reason I told that no current will go through R2 as the other path has no resistance. So the current will flow through zero resistance.

Comment: How did you reason that R2 has no current and that R3 current is to the left?

Comment: R2 should not have any current as the other path has zero resistance (I think). After that the main current divides in i1 ans i2 which flow through R3 and R4 respectively. But i1 don't flow through R2 as the other path has no resistance.  I'm not quit sure about it, but I think the current should flow like this. 

Comment: If R2, R3, and R4 are in parallel (and none of them has a value of 0 or infinity) then if there is current through one of them there must be current through all of them.

Comment: See this question. Same circuit if you replace the series resistances with just one resistance https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/483706/can-current-travel-backwards/483739#483739

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can current travel backwards?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/483706/can-current-travel-backwards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason why the current should be $0$ on the $R_2$ branch just because there is a wire connecting the node to another part of the circuit. To see this, consider the case where $R_3$ and $R_4$ are arbitrarily large. You will probably agree that in that case,  the wire connecting the node to the left of $R_2$ to the other part of the circuit is essentially open, so it shouldn't prevent the current from flowing through $R_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Have you yet considered superposition?
The current through the above circuit can be visualised as superposition of 2 current diagrams. You've made only one part of it.

**For the first case**

Let's imagine a current $I$ enters point A. And let it follow the same turns like your diagram. It enters the no- resistance wire and rest you know.

[image]

**For the second case**

Let's consider the $I$ current exiting point B. Through its journey, let's assume it reached there by moving through no-resistance wire. Before that, it must have hit the junction of $R_3$ and $R_4$. The current must be constituted of the two currents flowing through $R_3$ and $R_4$. The current through $R_4$ must have come from the no-resistance wire. Both these currents must have originated from point A.

[image]

This story sounds familiar. Right? Due to geometrically symmetrical nature of the diagram, the current in incoming and outgoing halves have similar path.

Thus, the net current through the circuit would be superposition of these incoming and outgoing halves of the circuit. This would look like...

[image]

So, if the current $i=2I$ enters point A, the above would be the correct current flow diagram.

Doubts? You can check the validity of the diagram for any specific values of $R_1, R_2, R_3 \space and \space R_4$.

PS: I forgot marking the resistors, can you please do it yourself?